# Contacts Import issue at CRM_Contact_Import_Form_MapField::getLocationTypeLabel

Tags: import, data-import, csv, location-type

Not a question as such, rather an observation.
WordPress contacts import from CSV, CiviCRM 5.61.2. (not reproduceable on dmaster).

`Uncaught TypeError: Return value of CRM_Contact_Import_Form_MapField::getLocationTypeLabel() must be of the type string, null returned in www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Form/MapField.php:480`

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** Apparently this happens if some Location Types have no Labels.

---

Rather simple fix: change from

- `protected function getLocationTypeLabel($type): string {`

to

- `protected function getLocationTypeLabel($type): ?string {`

in **www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Form/MapField.php:480**

however not sure it's the right thing to do.

Comment: The question really is whether it is valid not to have a label.  If it is, then it should probably return an empty string rather than null so changing the next line may be better to become:  `return $this->getLocationTypes()[$type] ?? '';`     Since it is not causing a problem on master then it may have been addressed in a different way already but if you want to post a PR someone will review and either accept your change or suggest a better way - be sure to include a valid scenario where the label is blank.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have an address location type without a label. It's a required field. Do you have an address type without a label? If not, it sounds like something else is broken.

Comment: Aidan, LarsSG : thank you for pointers, now I realise where this came from (empty Location Type labels) - thought initially this is because  Primary location type has been disabled ( not deleted ) at /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FlocationType&reset=1 Not sure why this has been configured like so, however it throws an error so maybe worth patching one way or another.